# Git detects directory with extension as file

Tags: git, file, directory

I'm using Git as repository,

For a strong reason, i've got a folder called `name.gid` with files inside.
When `git add .` it's added as a file (because of the extension?) but none of its inner files are added.

Is there any way to specify Git that `name.gid` is a folder?

Comment: Is `name.git` itself a git repository?  If so you cannot add it to another git repository using `git add`.

Comment: Is it `name.gid` or `name.git`? What makes you think that it's added *as a file*?

Comment: @larsks  its .gid not .git

Comment: @keith-thompson its .gid not .git

Comment: When asking technical question you need to pay special attention to the spelling of filenames; typos make our lives difficult.

Comment: You'll see exactly the same behavior with a directory name that doesn't contain a `.` character.

Comment: What's `find -name .git` say?

Comment: FWIW, I just tried this on my Windows machine and `git add .` added a directory with an extension, along with all of its files with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

After `git commit` you can use `git ls-files .` to check what files are in the repository.

Comment: That image doesn't tell us much. If you've added the directory, and there were files  under the directory at the time you added it, then `git status` should show those files. `git commit` will then commit those files.

Comment: @KeithThompson `git status` does not show the files and subdirectories from the newly added directories. It only shows directories. After `git commit` -> edit file -> `git add .`, `git status` displays the modified files.

Comment: @KeithThompson You are right. I just tested it too. I guess I mistaken it with the behaviour of `git status` regarding the files in the subdirectories that were not yet added. I removed the part about `git add` and `git status` from the answer. *(thinking about removing the answer altogether)*

Comment: @JGInternational Since Git cannot track empty folders, but can only add files, you cannot add just a folder. The folder in that screenshot is also not showing the normal folder icon or behaving like a folder. Are you sure that `kratos.gid` is a normal folder? It looks more like a submodule to me.

Answer (score 0):

Git has no problem with directory names with embedded `.` characters. It treats them no differently than any other valid directory name.

I'm not sure why you think that the directory is "added as a file"; it almost certainly isn't.

Quoting the `git add` man page (`git add --help`):

> `<pathspec>...`
>   Files to add content from. Fileglobs (e.g.  `*.c`) can be given to add
>   all matching files. Also a leading directory name (e.g.  `dir` to add
>   `dir/file1` and `dir/file2`) can be given to add all files in
>   the directory, recursively.

An example I just ran on my own system:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/kst/2015-06-04/.git/
$ mkdir foo.dir
$ cd foo.dir
$ echo hello > hello.txt
$ git add .
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   hello.txt

$
```

As you can see, running `git add` on a directory added a file under that directory. A subsequent `git commit` would commit that file to the repository.

Is this consistent with the behavior you're seeing?

If files are not being added when you add a directory, one possibility is that the file names are ignored due to a `.gitignore` file.